# No "show hidden icons" icon (triangle) in Plasma 5 Tray when panel on top

Tags: linux, kde-plasma

In Plasma 5 when panel is on top there is no "show hidden icons" triangle icon. Although clicking empty space between Tray and Clock shows all the icons. The triangle image isn't showed when panel is on top, it's present only when panel is on the bottom/right/left side of the screen.

[image: Before clicking]

[image: After clicking]

It was also bugged in KDE4. How to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's fixed in the latest Plasma. Glassified theme is somehow broken. Breeze is ok.